# How to add a string with superscript in an THREE.TextGeometry?

Tags: javascript, string, three.js

I'm working on a dimensioning tool with Three.js. 
I would like to write dimensioning of distances over a line between two objects.
I want to write 2.45<sup>5</sup> as shown in the picture.
[image]

Sadly, as in Threejs R88 is HTML encoding not possible to get, for example, the superscript function in TextGeometry.  A solution would be to append a second text geometry (with the superscript number) to the main one. But I would like to avoid this solution since I think it's not a very wise/clean one. 
Do you have any ideas how to solve this?

someting like this doesn't work obviously:

```
var ss = '5'.sup();

var geometry = new THREE.TextGeometry( '2.45' + ss, {
        font: font,
        size: 80,
        height: 5});
```

Thank you in advance, I'm open to every suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`Font`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/extras/core/Font) you load must support the characters you want to use.

After a brief inspection, I was able to find "²" in the `helvetiker_regular.typeface.json` font file. That does not guarantee that it will include the characters you're looking for. For example, I was unable to find a definition for "⁶" in the same file.

Of course, the easiest workaround is to create normal-scale numbers, then scale/position them into a suberscript position. Three.js also provides methods for combining geometries, so you would make fewer meshes in the process (addressing your "not clean" concern).

Comment: You're perfectly right. That font (`helvetiker_regular.typeface.json`) doesn't support most of such symbols, as I got just normal characters for 2 and 3, the others are just question marks :). [link](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/x1fdffxq/)

Comment: @prisoner849 What makes it harder is the provided (examples, granted) font files aren't arranged in any logical character/glyph order. So even if you find a specific glyph definition (e.g. "A" = index 194), there's no guarantee the next-value glyph definition will be anywhere near the definition of the first (e.g. "B" = index 71). /rant

Comment: @TheJim01 thank you for your answer. yeah, one solution is to find the right font, the other combining geometries. Sadly are both not the one I wished for :)

Comment: @TheJim01 I've seen that glyph have an SVG structure, so theoretically, I can add in the JSON object font a new glyph ⁵

Answer (score -1):

A solution could be the use of the following characters:

⁰ ¹ ² ³ ⁴ ⁵ ⁶ ⁷ ⁸ ⁹

Those are created via ALT characters. 
[link](https://www.keynotesupport.com/websites/special-characters-math-currency.shtml)

They should work in Three.js.

Comment: Before you offer a solution, could you please [try it](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/x1fdffxq/) yourself.