# Can't display special german characters in typeface for Three.js

Tags: fonts, three.js, utf-16

I downloaded Roboto.ttf font and used [typeface.js](https://gero3.github.io/facetype.js/) to convert the font to .json and load it with Three.js

```
                        var loader = new THREE.FontLoader();
                    loader.load( 'fonts/Roboto Mono_Regular.json', function ( font ) {
                        var geometry = new THREE.TextGeometry( 'äüö', {
                            font: font,
                            size: 80,
                            height: 2,
                            curveSegments: 12,
                            bevelEnabled: true,
                            bevelThickness: 10,
                            bevelSize: 2,
                            bevelSegments: 5
                        });
                      var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ambient: 0x000000, color: 0x000000});
                      label = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
                      label.name = "label"
                      label.scale.set(0.01,0.01,0.01);
                      label.rotation.y = 1.57;
                      label.position.set(0.85,-0.32,1);
                      scene.add(label);
                    });
```

But it only displays: ??? - The Roboto font contains those characters, and also the converted .json has those characters in the glyphs. All files have same encoding. How can I fix this? The same with polnish characters; I think I need utf-16.

Reconverted the Font, have still some issues. While writing: "öÖäÄüÜ"
[image]

Solved:

**The problem was that I ticked the option "Reverse font direction.
Use this to fix issues with holes in characters like 'd', 'o' and '8'." on facetype.js - without that check, it works!**

Comment: I don't think the problem is in the code you posted above. Do more common characters, like `aeiou` show up? Any chance you could post the font JSON file in a https://jsfiddle.net/ or https://codepen.io/ I have a feeling it has something to do with that data.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47288699/how-to-add-a-string-with-superscript-in-an-three-textgeometry/47289165#47289165) should clear things up for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that your .json file doesn't contain the correct glyphs for the special characters you're using. Three.js recommends using [Facetype.js](http://gero3.github.io/facetype.js/) to convert your fonts to .json format.

I just used it to convert Roboto Mono and it works out just fine. As you can see below.

[image]

Comment: as I wrote in my original question: I am using Facetype.js - Still can't see the characters. Don't know where the problem is.

Comment: could you upload your json somewhere? for me ä ö is not working, ü is.

Comment: I saw that you just marked this as correct, did you manage to do it? Which fonts you need just Roboto or Roboto Mono as well? I can help you with that, no problem.

Comment: Its working with both, I took "Roboto Mono Medium" - The real problem was with the ticking of "Reverse font direction." option on TypeFace.js Now it works

Comment: Glad to hear it :)